# XCart Disable Checkout Button If Specific Item Is In Cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, smarty, x-cart

I have this code I'm using in XCart 4.6 to hide a checkout button.

```
{section name=product loop=$products}
    {if $products[product].productid eq 3065}
    &nbsp;
    {else}
  <a href="http://academyprohair.com/cart.php" style="margin-top:5px;"><img src="{$AltImagesDir}/button_checkout.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    {/if}
    {/section}
```

It works perfectly on the cart page but it breaks on every other page and it hides the checkout button regardless of what item is in the cart.

Comment: Can you clarify when it works and does not?  On the cart page, if productid = 3065 then it shows the space, otherwise it shows the link.      On other pages it always shows the space, never the link?

Comment: Correct. it only shows the space on the cart.php page in XCart but not any other section of the site like home.php or product.php. So basically it only works during the checkout process and I want it to work throughout the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your question:

Array `{$products}` that holds items in Cart is available only on Cart and Checkout page(s). You cannot use it on other pages, because it does not exist.

**The way you check if specific item is in cart is wrong** in first place. The code you provided will print for example 5 links to Cart if you have 5 products in Cart which have no `id=3065`.

So, lets find a solution. Since you need to check if one product is in Cart on every page (to hide Checkout link), than you need to create PHP script that checks for item existence. We shall set global smarty variable `is_product_in_cart`, which you can use anywhere you want in TPL files. The xcart core file we shall change is `home.php` on root, we shall add code before we show the template (before ending `func_display('customer/home.tpl', $smarty);`):

```
/* academyprohair.com custom code */
$my_products = func_products_in_cart($cart);
$is_product_in_cart = 'N';
foreach( $my_products as $product ) {
    if ( $product['productid']==3065 ) {
        $is_product_in_cart = 'Y';
        break;
    };
};
$smarty->assign('is_product_in_cart', $is_product_in_cart);
```

In your templates, everywhere except on Cart and Checkout pages, you can show the cart link easy with:

```
{if $is_product_in_cart neq 'Y' }
    <a href="http://academyprohair.com/cart.php" style="margin-top:5px;"><img src="{$AltImagesDir}/button_checkout.jpg" alt="" /></a>
{/if}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! For those looking to do this, if you want it to work on other parts of the site you simply add the custom code to files like pages.php or cart.php in the root folder and then use the if statement.

Comment: P.S. You should update your Sitemap and About Us links at footer + favicon.